# How to get the hashed name of a file that was uploaded with Laravel Livewire in the tests

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am trying to write a test for the following Livewire component that uploads an image:

```
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;

class UploadImage extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;

    public $image;

    public function save()
    {
        $this->validate([
            'image' => 'image|mimes:jpg,jpeg',
        ]);

        $storedImage = $this->image->store('images'); // returns e.g. "images/PznpCCFUUDjZuZRDEAGpsr7SxV2qIM2dEsZ3l0zO.jpeg"

        // save $storedImage as the name in the images table 
    }
}
```

The test below fails because the file is saved to the disk and db with the hashed name and not `test.jpg`. How do I get the hashed name that was created by Livewire for the image in the test?

The `$storedImage` in the component is not the same as the `$image->hashName()` in the test

```
/** @test **/
function it_can_upload_an_image() {
    Storage::fake();

    $image = UploadedFile::fake()->image('test.jpeg');

    Livewire::test(UploadImage::class)
        ->set('image', $image)
        ->call('save');

    $this->assertDatabaseHas('images', [
        'name' => "images/{$image->hashName()}",
    ]);

    Storage::assertExists("images/{$image->hashName()}");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer in the source code's tests [here](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/blob/1.x/tests/FileUploadsTest.php#L106). The solution is so simple ‍♂️

Add a public property to the component for the `$storedImage` so that it can be accessed in the tests.

e.g.

```
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;

class UploadImage extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;

    public $image;

    public $storedImage;

    public function save()
    {
        $this->validate([
            'image' => 'image|mimes:jpg,jpeg',
        ]);

        $this->storedImage = $this->image->store('images');

        // save $storedImage as the name in the images table 
    }
}
```

Now the hashed name can be accessed from the test like:

```
/** @test **/
function it_can_upload_an_image() {
    Storage::fake();

    $image = UploadedFile::fake()->image('test.jpeg');

    $storedImage = Livewire::test(UploadImage::class)
        ->set('image', $image)
        ->call('save')
        ->get('storedImage');

    $this->assertDatabaseHas('images', [
        'name' => $storedImage,
    ]);

    Storage::assertExists($storedImage);
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to get original name of the uploaded file, you may do so using the getClientOriginalName method

So you can do

```
$this->file->getClientOriginalName()
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
$validatedData = $this->validate();
$imageName = $this->image->store('public/events');
$validatedData['image'] = str_replace("public/events/", "", $imageName);
```