# Laravel test file upload returns null

Tags: laravel, testing, upload

I'm trying to test a file upload, the controller always returns `null` for `$request->file('file')`

Here is my test

```
test('can upload file', function () {
  Storage::fake('local');

  $file = UploadedFile::fake()->image('avatar.jpg');

  $this->post(route('admin.ajax.files.store', [
     'file' => $file
  ]));

  Storage::disk('local')->assertExists($file->hashName());
});
```

Then in the controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->file('file'));
}
```

outputs null

if I look at `$request->file`, I see

```
array:1 [
  "name" => "avatar.jpg"
]
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong to test uploading a file without actually uploading a file.

Comment: Not sure if this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63501268/how-to-get-the-hashed-name-of-a-file-that-was-uploaded-with-laravel-livewire-in

Comment: Thanks, Marc in this case I'm not using Livewire this is a regular Laravel controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the array to `->post()`

```
$this->post(route('admin.ajax.files.store'), [
     'file' => $file
  ]);
```